# How to create a extension function to make rx subscription to flowable cleaner?

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java2, rx-android, rx-kotlin

I'm developing an android app using room and RxAndroid. The problem is that i'm using the next code to refresh the info in my recycler view.

```
observable.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe{adapter.data = it}
```

if i implement this in my activity it works like a charm. But i want to create an extension function to make the code cleaner when using flowables from the database. I create this funtion

```
fun <T> Flowable<T>.uiSubscribe(x : (T) -> Unit)  {
this.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe{x}
```

but when i tried to use it, it does nothing. It doesn't trow an error or anything. Does somebody know a way to archive this? or does somebody know why it is not working?

Comment: "uiSubscribe" this name is very misleading. Also don't put answers in your question, post them as answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `subscribe { x(it) }` or `subscribe(x)`.

In your case `subscribe{x}` creates an `onNext` consumer which does nothing but state `x` in the expression.